# Unable to insert FK value to a table

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I am trying to insert values to a table that has a FK from other table. In my example

I have created a Location Table and insert values.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FZjj.png)

I have created a Cabin Table with Location ID as FK, I can't select Location ID from the drop down list.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y1mi.png)

However, when I inspect the table, it has locationID as column

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lllT.png)

Any idea? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance, I checked on the web and couldn't get anything substantial

Comment: How are you creating the tables? By writing SQL, by using the editor in MSSQLSMS, from EntityFramework?

The screenshots suggest that you have a wrong column name. The fact that `location` is blue means that MSSQLSMS thinks that it could be a reserved word and therefore you might have to write `[location]` instead.

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text, appropriately formatted. Also, you seem to be trying to insert into a column called location when the column name is locationId

Comment: Please provide some code in formatted typing, without using images

Comment: The table column is LocationID. Your insert statement is specifying "location". Change it to LocationID and you should be set.